# Auto add days to datetime as each days passes in mysql

Tags: mysql, datetime

I want to make a column in mysql database that when user login first time in system, it stores that datetime in mysql table. And since that day in other column days will add according to his register date. Like 1, 2, 3,....and so on. So, is there any way I can achieve the results? Please guide me soon.

Comment: i guess [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_adddate) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with just one column (to hold the registration / first login date) and the DATEDIFF function:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  ID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  registered_at datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

INSERT INTO users SET
name = 'myname',
registered_at = NOW();

SELECT registered_at, DATEDIFF(NOW(), registered_at) AS days_since
FROM users
WHERE name = 'myname';
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for answer, but may i know what will be the result of DATEDIFF(NOW(), registered_at)...because I want this result in integer format like 80 or 90....I hope you understood my I want. Thank you once again.

Comment: Yes, that will be an integer -
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff

Comment: Hey, one thing I would like to know ...what to do if I want absolute value of DATEDIFF...I mean is it of if I use ABS(DATEDIFF(NOW(), registered_at)).... is it valid?